# Secure Connection, NSURLSession to Django Rest API

Tags: https, django-rest-framework, nsurlsession, django-sslify

More of a question of understanding rather than looking for a technical solution. I'm on a team working to build an iOS application that needs database support. We're using Swift for the application code. A Django REST API wraps a MySQL database on the backend. The two are communicating over HTTP using Swift's NSURLSession class.

We will be passing password information over one of the http requests, and so we want to up the requests to HTTPS. On the API side we can force traffic through SSL middleware using [django-ssilfy](https://github.com/rdegges/django-sslify).

My concern is that including this library does nothing on the client-side. As far as I know we will only need to change the url to include 'https://' rather than 'http://'. It seems that the data passed will only be secure once it *reaches the API*, rather than over the *entire connection*.

Is there anything we must do to secure the data being passed over the NSURLSession on Wi-Fi and mobile networks? Or is simply pointing the session at an API view that is throttled through a SSL port enough to ensure the request is secure?

Please let me know if I am way off track or if there is any steps other than [django-ssilfy](https://github.com/rdegges/django-sslify) that I should take in order to make all http communication secure!

Go SO!

Answer (score 1):

This question is more about whether or not SSL is secure, and less about if any of the tools that are being used make it less secure.

Luckily the [Information Security Stack Exchange has your answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work) with an in-depth explanation as to how TLS *does* help secure your application.

---

When it comes to securing your Django site though, `django-sslify` is a good start, but it's not the magic cure to security issues. If you can, it's recommended to not serve insecure responses, which works well for API hosts (`api.github.com` is one example), but not if your API is hosted on the same domain as your front-end application. There are other Django apps available that are recommended, [such as djang-secure](https://github.com/carljm/django-secure/) (parts of which were [integrated into Django 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.8/#security-enhancements)).

You should also follow the [Django security recommendations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/security/), and revisit them with new major releases. There are other resources you can look at, like ["Is Django's built-in security enough"](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/27805/is-djangos-built-in-security-enough) and [many](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8964/trying-to-make-a-django-based-site-use-https-only-not-sure-if-its-secure) [other](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/47198/is-djangos-built-in-csrf-protection-enough) [questions](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/61909/django-secret-key-security-how-are-methods-more-secure) on the [Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/).